# shell-script headers (#!/bin/sh vs #!/bin/csh)

Tags: shell, unix

Why do all script files start with

```
#!/bin/sh
```

or with

```
#!/bin/csh
```

Is that required? What's the purpose of this? And what's the difference between the two?

Comment: For a csh script, you should use `#!/bin/csh -f`; the `-f` tells the shell not to source the user's `.login` and `.cshrc`, which makes the script run faster and avoids dependencies on the user's setup. (Or better yet, don't write csh scripts.) Don't use `-f` for sh or bash scripts; it doesn't have the same meaning.

Comment: it's a fair question and a classic but "is it required" can also be answered empirically. Mostly... no, not at all.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

This is known as a `Shebang`:

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)

> #!interpreter [optional-arg]

A shebang is only relevant when a script has the execute permission (e.g. chmod u+x script.sh).

When a shell executes the script it will use the specified interpreter.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
# file: foo.sh
echo 1

$ chmod u+x foo.sh
$ ./foo.sh
  1
```

Comment: @Kolob Canyon you do not need to, but it can help some editors with syntax highlighting (although there are usually other ways to achieve the same thing): https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88730/193985

Answer (score 60):

The `#!` line tells the kernel (specifically, the implementation of the [`execve`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) system call) that this program is written in an interpreted language; the absolute pathname that follows identifies the interpreter.  Programs compiled to machine code begin with a different byte sequence -- on most modern Unixes, `7f 45 4c 46` (<kbd>^?ELF</kbd>) that identifies them as such.

You can put an absolute path to *any program you want* after the `#!`, as long as that program is not itself a `#!` script.  The kernel rewrites an invocation of

```
./script arg1 arg2 arg3 ...
```

where `./script` starts with, say, `#! /usr/bin/perl`, as if the command line had actually been

```
/usr/bin/perl ./script arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Or, as you have seen, you can use `#! /bin/sh` to write a script intended to be interpreted by `sh`.

The `#!` line is only processed if you *directly* invoke the script (`./script` on the command line); the file must also be executable (`chmod +x script`).  If you do `sh ./script` the `#!` line is not necessary (and will be ignored if present), and the file does not have to be executable.  The *point* of the feature is to allow you to directly invoke interpreted-language programs without having to know what language they are written in.  (Do `grep '^#!' /usr/bin/*` -- you will discover that a great many stock programs are in fact using this feature.)

Here are some rules for using this feature:

- The `#!` must be the very first two *bytes* in the file.  In particular, the file *must* be in an ASCII-compatible encoding (e.g. UTF-8 will work, but UTF-16 won't) and *must not* start with a "byte order mark", or the kernel will not recognize it as a `#!` script.
- The path after `#!` must be an absolute path (starts with `/`).  It cannot contain space, tab, or newline characters.
- It is good style, but not required, to put a space between the `#!` and the `/`.  Do not put more than one space there.
- You cannot put shell variables on the `#!` line, they will not be expanded.
- You can put *one* command-line argument after the absolute path, separated from it by a single space.  Like the absolute path, this argument cannot contain space, tab, or newline characters. Sometimes this is necessary to get things to work (`#! /usr/bin/awk -f`), sometimes it's just useful (`#! /usr/bin/perl -Tw`).  Unfortunately, you cannot put *two* or more arguments after the absolute path.
- Some people will tell you to use `#! /usr/bin/env interpreter` instead of `#! /absolute/path/to/interpreter`. **This is almost always a mistake.** It makes your program's behavior depend on the `$PATH` variable of the user who invokes the script.  And not all systems have `env` in the first place.
- Programs that need `setuid` or `setgid` privileges can't use `#!`; they have to be compiled to machine code.  (If you don't know what `setuid` is, don't worry about this.)

Regarding `csh`, it relates to `sh` roughly as Nutrimat [Advanced Tea Substitute](http://everything2.com/title/Advanced+tea+substitute) does to tea.  It has (or rather had; modern implementations of `sh` have caught up) a number of advantages over `sh` for interactive usage, but using it (or its descendant `tcsh`) for scripting is [almost always a mistake](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/CshTop10.txt).  If you're new to shell scripting in general, I strongly recommend you ignore it and focus on `sh`.  If you are using a `csh` relative as your login shell, switch to `bash` or `zsh`, so that the interactive command language will be the same as the scripting language you're learning.

Comment: Recent versions of Linux do allow the specified interpreter to be a script. It's common practice to omit the space after the `#!`; no comment on whether that's good style. See [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608/10454) and [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620/10454) for a discussion of the pros and cons of the `#!/usr/bin/env` hack.

Comment: @KeithThompson I'm under the impression Linux is the *only* common Unix variant that allows the interpreter to be a script, so it's still not something to rely on.  Since I wrote this I've myself encountered a situation where `#!/usr/bin/env` was the Right Thing, but it remains my opinion that it is almost always a bad idea.

Answer (score 10):

This defines what shell (command interpreter) you are using for interpreting/running your script. Each shell is slightly different in the way it interacts with the user and executes scripts (programs).

When you type in a command at the Unix prompt, you are interacting with the shell.

E.g., `#!/bin/csh` refers to the C-shell, `/bin/tcsh` the t-shell, `/bin/bash` the bash shell, etc.

You can tell which interactive shell you are using the

```
 echo $SHELL
```

command, or alternatively

```
 env | grep -i shell
```

You can change your command shell with the `chsh` command.

Each has a slightly different command set and way of assigning variables and its own set of programming constructs. For instance the if-else statement with bash looks different that the one in the C-shell.

[This page](http://joelinoff.com/blog/?page_id=235) might be of interest as it "translates" between bash and tcsh commands/syntax.

Using the directive in the shell script allows you to run programs using a different shell. For instance I use the `tcsh` shell interactively, but often run bash scripts using /bin/bash in the script file.

Aside:

This concept extends to other scripts too. For instance if you program in Python you'd put

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
```

at the top of your Python program

Comment: So is it required? How do I know which shell I'm really using?

Comment: So if I'm writing the scripts for someone to use on their machine, and I don't know what shell they are using. (This person, unfortunately, is clueless about this stuff, thus all he can do is to run the script without changing a thing). Can I do something like `#! $SHELL` ? Would this put the correct shell in the Shebang?

Comment: @OneTwoThree Most systems have the standard shells, if you write a bash or csh script you'll be ok. What shell they are using interactively **doesn't** matter, that is the beauty of the e.g., `!#/bin/bash`directive. It tells the system what shell to use to execute your shell script.

Comment: The value of `$SHELL` doesn't necessarily tell you which shell you're running at the moment; it normally tells you your *default* shell. tcsh sets `$version` and `$tcsh`; bash sets `$BASH_VERSION`. Not all shells necessarily have similar mechanisms.

Comment: @OneTwoThree: The `#!` line has to match the syntax of the script, *not* the interactive shell used by whoever is running the script.