# The code that runs when you type `node` at the terminal

Tags: c, node.js, bash, terminal

I am trying to learn how the shebang works, and wondering what happens when you type `node` at the terminal prompt. Wondering if it calls `main` in one of the [c functions](https://github.com/nodejs/node/tree/a4ce449bb7b0e2f9edba75baf2a2f652a6750454/src) somewhere. I understand only the basics, having been using node for a while. The shebang `#!/usr/bin/env node` somehow reads the node executable, which I'm not sure what or where it is, and what it starts at. Then there is the code that actually evaluates the expression `node` and directs it to the shebang, but that's probably too complicated to ask about.

Comment: It depends heavily on the OS and type of executable. Is this GNU/Linux? No shebang is generally involved when you type `node` at the terminal. Is your question "How does the shell run an executable like `node`?" or "How does the shell run a script with a shebang like `#!/usr/bin/env node`?"

Comment: Ok then yeah just knowing what happens when I type `node`, where it first hits the line of code in the c library, if at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To be excruciatingly precise, "the shebang" is just the two characters `#!`.  When a file on a Unix system is invoked as an executable (ultimately via the system call [`execve`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)), the kernel looks at its first few bytes to determine what *kind* of executable it is.  If those bytes identify it as containing machine code, then the kernel will load the machine code into memory and cause the CPU to begin executing it.  If the machine code was compiled from a C program, its `main` function will eventually get called.  (If you want to know how *this* process works, read the book "Linkers and Loaders" by John Levine.)

But if the first two bytes are `#` and `!` (ASCII values 35 and 33) then the kernel will instead scan the first line of the file for the name of an *interpreter*, and then it will run the interpreter instead, supplying the name of the `#!` program as a command-line argument.  (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591086/shell-script-headers-bin-sh-vs-bin-csh/10591577#10591577) for the exact details of how the first line is parsed by the kernel.)  If you do

```
./foo.js a b c d
```

and foo.js begins with `#! /usr/bin/node`, then the kernel will behave as if `execve` had been called with the argument vector

```
/usr/bin/node ./foo.js a b c d
```

and it will open up the file `/usr/bin/node`, discover that that is a machine-code executable, and proceed to load the machine code, which is the Node interpreter, and run it.  Node's `main` function will then notice that its first argument is `./foo.js`, and it will open that file and execute it as a Javascript program, rather than going into its interactive read-evaluate-print loop.

The Node interpreter itself ignores the the `#!` line—but it has to have code in its parser to ignore it; the kernel doesn't filter it out.  With many of the interpreted languages commonly used on Unix (sh, awk, perl, python, ruby, ...) comments run from a `#` to the end of the line, so this happens automatically; in fact, the `#!` notation was chosen, back in the day, *because* sh comments were from `#` to the end of the line. Javascript comments don't work like that, so Node has to have a special case for `#!` at the beginning of the file.

---

The `#!` line you showed has an additional level of indirection: `#! /usr/bin/env node` makes the kernel run the program `/usr/bin/env` (which is again made of machine code) with the argument vector

```
/usr/bin/env node ./foo.js a b c d
```

`env` then sees that its first argument is `node` and it looks along the *search path* for executables for a program named `node`.  The search path is defined by an environment variable: type

```
echo $PATH
```

at your prompt to learn what it is.  It's a colon-separated list of directories.  For instance, a common value for PATH is

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

which means to look in the directories `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/bin`, and `/bin`, in that order, for programs; in other words, with that value of PATH, and the arguments above, `env` would first attempt to run

```
/usr/local/bin/node ./foo.js a b c d
```

and if that didn't work it would try `/usr/bin/node` and so on.  This extra indirection is necessary if you don't know where the Node interpreter (or whatever) has been installed, because the kernel's `#!` processing will only accept an absolute pathname after `#!`; it won't do a PATH search for you.  If you do know where `node` has been installed, it's better to write that pathname directly, so that your program's behavior doesn't depend on what the invoking user's PATH is (e.g. [some Linux distributions used to use the name `/usr/bin/node` for a completely unrelated program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168141/cannot-install-packages-using-node-package-manager-in-ubuntu), so if you had `#! /usr/bin/env node` and the user didn't have `/opt/node-1.9/bin` before `/usr/bin` on their PATH, hilarity would ensue).

---

The behavior I have described for `execve` and files beginning with `#!` is *not* [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) (it is *mentioned* on that page, but only in the non-normative RATIONALE section).  However, it is consistent across all Unix-like operating systems you are likely to encounter nowadays.  I don't know off the top of my head exactly how old it is.